# Is it possible to insert a multi line comment tag into an xml

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.9

how to generate multi line comment in xml using custom script

```
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <!--
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        -->
        <description>Two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>            
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

Comment: The question seems bit unclear. Could you please let me know what exactly is required?

Comment: Actually i have try to add multiple line comment i have create php file in my module and write above code in my file

Comment: Another blind closing.

Comment: still not clear regarding what  you are trying to achieve? are you saying you want to comment in xml file??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to comment out a block then this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <!--
        <testmodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </testmodule>
        -->
    </modules>
</config>
```

Is the right way to do it and it should work.